# Is this the proper use of Action<T>

Tags: c#, delegates

As I understand Func and Action; An Action does not return a value, and a Func does. In the below example I have a child class create an instance of "SomeContent" and pass a reference back to the parent class. My questions are:

1. Does  this.ContentDelagate(content) pass by reference or by value?
2. In the below example, should I have used Func as I want a reference to an the instantiated SomeContent object? If so can you provide an example?

---

```
namespace DelegateTut
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestClass myTest = new TestClass();

            myTest.ContentDelagate += ContentDelegateHandler;       
            myTest.RunDel();          


            Console.Write("Press Enter to exit...\n");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static void ContentDelegateHandler(SomeContent content) {

            Console.WriteLine(content.ValueOne);
            Console.WriteLine(content.ValueTwo);

        }     

    }
}

public class TestClass {

    public TestClass() { }   

    public Action<SomeContent> ContentDelagate { get; set; }   

    public void RunDel() {

        SendContentToMainThread();

    }   

    public void SendContentToMainThread() {

        SomeContent content = new SomeContent { 

            ValueOne = "Hello",
            ValueTwo = "World"

        };

        this.ContentDelagate(content);
    }   

}

public class SomeContent {

    public String ValueOne { get; set; }
    public String ValueTwo { get; set; }
    public SomeContent() { }

}
```

Comment: C# always passes by value by default...however, that is often the reference...http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Yes, C# passes by value by default (@JustinPihony). However, if the type is a reference type, then it is the reference (handle) that is passed by value - i.e., you get a copy of the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this.ContentDelagate(content) pass by reference or by value?

This question is a little confusing.  We are dealing with both a getter and a delegate as well.  I think its clearer to show:

```
    public void SendContentToMainThread()
    {

        SomeContent content = new SomeContent
        {

            ValueOne = "Hello",
            ValueTwo = "World"

        };

        Action<SomeContent>  myDel = ContentDelagate;//Property Get 
        myDel(content);//invoke delegate

        Console.WriteLine(content.ValueOne);//refer to this below
    }
```

The handler is called as part of the multicast delegate.  The handler is being passed a class which is a reference type.  In C# reference and value types are passed by value.  The underlying value that is copied could be a value (value type) or a location in memory (reference type).

Because this is a reference type it has reference type behavior:

```
        public static void ContentDelegateHandler(SomeContent content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(content.ValueOne);
            Console.WriteLine(content.ValueTwo);

            content.ValueOne = "updated";
        }
```

Now the modified code above `Console.WriteLine(content.ValueOne);` will print out the word "updated".

> In the below example, should I have used Func as I want a reference to
>   an the instantiated SomeContent object? If so can you provide an
>   example?

There's nothing being returned in this case so no you should not use Func.  Func does not have any impact whatsoever on your desire to have reference type behavior.